# Rails add to join table from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**Goal:** find or create a category and add it to the join table when parsing through feed

UPDATED:

```
has_many :category_feeds
has_many :categories, :through => :category_feeds

  def self.nokogiri_get_feed(url)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    doc.search('feed entry').each do |item|
      unless exists? :guid => item.css('id').text
        categories = []
        item.xpath('content').each do |i|
          i.css('subject').each do |subject|
            name = subject['subjectname']
            categories << Category.find_or_create_by_name(name)
          end
        end
        create!(:name => item.css('title').text, :url => item.at_css("link")[:href], :guid => item['id'], :categories => categories)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
categories << Category.find_or_create_by_name(name)
```

I'd recommend reading more in the [associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference)

Comment: Looked at guide, but between your input and http://railspikes.com/2008/8/11/understanding-map-and-reduce got it working.  Updated question with possible answer, but is this right?  Had to add categories = [] and move the create after subject.

Comment: Only if you've mis-stated your goal, and actually you want to **replace** any existing categories with new ones, not **add** to them as you've asked.